# Test class for the Trigger

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex-code

I am fairly new to salesforce and i am trying to write a test class for a trigger. I tried writing a test class.

Any help is much appreciated in correcting the test class

**I am writing a test class for the Trigger Below**

```
Trigger Booking on Booking__c (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> cancelledBookingIds = new Set<Id>(); 
    for (Booking__c booking: Trigger.new) {
        if (booking.Booking_Type__c == 'cancelled') {
            cancelledBookingIds.add(booking.id);
        }    
    }
    List<Booking_Item__c> bookingItemsForCancelling = [SELECT Booking_Type__c
                                                       FROM Booking_Item__c
                                                       WHERE Booking__c IN: cancelledBookingIds];
    for (Booking_Item__c item: bookingItemsForCancelling) {
        item.Booking_Type__c = 'cancelled';
    }
    update bookingItemsForCancelling;
}
```

**Test Class for the trigger above**
@isTest
Public class BookingTest  {

```
static testMethod void testBookingStatus()  {
Booking_Item__c  bookingItemsForCancelling = new Booking_Item__c   (  Name='TestBookingItem');
insert bookingItemsForCancelling ;

// Set up the Booking_Item__c record.
        bookingItemsForCancelling = [SELECT Booking_Type__c 
                                     FROM Booking_Item__c
                                     WHERE Booking__c IN: cancelledBookingIds];
        System.assertEquals(null, bookingItemsForCancelling . Booking_Item__c);

// Set up the Booking__c record.
        String Booking__cName= 'My Booking';
        Booking __c Booking = new Booking (BookingId= bookingItemsForCancelling.Id, 
                                           Name= Booking __cName, );

// Cause the Trigger to execute.
        insert Booking;


// Verify that the results are as expected.
bookingItemsForCancelling = [SELECT Booking_Type__c 
                             FROM Booking_Item__c
                             WHERE Booking__c IN: cancelledBookingIds];

   }
}
```

**Error: Compile Error: Invalid identifier: Booking__cName at line 13 column 16**

After this error i removed the underscore on Booking__c Object. The next error is

**Error Error: Compile Error: line 14:16 no viable alternative at character '_' at line 14 column 16**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `Booking __c` instead of `Booking__c` (extra space) and an extra `,` in the constructor for the Booking in this line:

`Booking __c Booking = new Booking (BookingId= bookingItemsForCancelling.Id, 
                                           Name= Booking __cName, );`